# What is the more correct/efficient selector?

Tags: jquery, selector

```
$("select").change(function() {

                alert($("select option:selected").val());

            });
```

OR

```
$("select").change(function() {

            alert($(this).attr("value"));

            });
```

I am specifically looking at the selector used in the alert.  From my
testing the result in the same correct values to be displayed.

Answer (score 3):

They are **different**. The first will get the value of the first selected `<option>` in the DOM (in any of the `<select>` elements).

The second one will work fine, and of course, there are several variations that do the same thing

```
$("select").change(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
            });

$("select").change(function() {
            alert($('option:selected', this).val());
            });
```

to name a couple

Answer (score 1):

First of all they are not equivalent. The first will give you the value of the selected options of *any* `select` element while the second will give you the value only of the one you changed.

So you should absolutely use the second example.

Comment: the first will be the value of the first selected option in the DOM